# android: twitter OAuth XAuth

Tags: android, twitter, oauth, xauth

I need to public game result in user's twitter page. Is there a way to do it automatically using XAuth or OAuth (I saw a few aexamples and each one needs user actions). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to make user login to twitter at least once, then you can do the posting without user's intervention.

Comment: You mean save token somewhere?

Comment: yes, save the AccessToken or token and tokenSecret somewhere. use Twitter4J library.